# Python - How to change autopct text color to be white in a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
pie(fbfrac,labels = fblabel,autopct='%1.1f%%',pctdistance=0.8,startangle=90,colors=fbcolor)
```

I have the chart displaying just as I want it, with the exception that the text will stand out better inside the plot if it is white instead of black.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [`pyplot.pie` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie):

> Return value:
>
> If autopct is not None, return the tuple (patches, texts, autotexts),
>   where patches and      texts are as above, and autotexts is a list of
>   Text instances for the numeric labels.

You need to change the color of `autotexts`; this is done simply by `set_color()`:

```
_, _, autotexts = pie(fbfrac,labels = fblabel,autopct='%1.1f%%',pctdistance=0.8,startangle=90,colors=fbcolor)
for autotext in autotexts:
    autotext.set_color('white')
```

This yields (with [Hogs and Dogs example](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.htm)):
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly

Comment: Can u please give me a simple answer as kiril did. I mean can you make changes in his answer for my question? Separate color for label and textprops?

Comment: `textprops` is a dictionary that is passed to _all_ text objects in a piechart, so no, his answer cannot be used if you want separate colors for different text instances.

Answer (score 26):

You can do it in one line using `textprops` argument of `pyplot.pie`. It's simple:

```
plt.pie(data, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'color':"w"})
```

In your case:

```py
pie(fbfrac, labels=fblabel, autopct='%1.1f%%', pctdistance=0.8, startangle=90, colors=fbcolor, textprops={'color':"w"})
```

An enlightening example can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-and-donut-labels-py).

Comment: When I used this, it also turned my outside labels white, making them invisible.

Comment: @kiril can we have color change for labels also?

Comment: Separate color for label and separate color for autopct?

Comment: Hey great answer! Just a little question. In my piechart, I have both the labels and the autopct enabled. autopct white fontcolor is good as pie is colored. But labels are outside the pie in white is invisible as the axes background is white. How to only change color for autopct and not for labels?

Answer (score 12):

Pie object returns `patches, texts, autotexts`. You can loop through the `texts` and `autotext` and `set_color`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fblabels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fbfrac = [15, 30, 45, 10]
fbcolor = ["blue", "green", "red", "orange"]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches, texts, autotexts  = ax.pie(fbfrac, labels = fblabels, autopct='%1.1f%%',pctdistance=0.8,startangle=90,colors=fbcolor)
[text.set_color('red') for text in texts]
texts[0].set_color('blue')
[autotext.set_color('white') for autotext in autotexts]

plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Oty.png)

Moreover you can change the color for individual label, accessing the list item, e.g: `texts[0].set_color('blue')`

You can get more inspiration [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo2.html?highlight=textprops).